# What is the windows server equivalent of iptables?

Tags: windows, iptables, firewall, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I found [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/207620/windows-equivalent-of-iptables) however it is outdated and appears to be focused on consumer versions of Windows.

What is the Windows Server 2012+ equivalent of iptables?

Comment: I dont know if there is an better equivalent for Windows Server, but the basic tool which is preinstalled is the Windows Firewall with advanced security. You can set your own Rules manually. But i'm using on my Windows Server hardware firewalls(Fortigate) wich protects my Server much better(Fortigate doesnt use the Server Ressources to filter out the incomming Traffic ;)

Answer (score 5):

Windows Server 2012 has a built-in firewall, which can be managed from either GUI (running **wf.msc**) or **PowerShell**, using [Network Security Cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554906%28v=wps.630%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).